# Correspondence analysis

Tags: categorical-data, correspondence-analysis

I have a question. I have the following categorical data from an open text diary study:

- Individuals reported emotions in different situations.
- Each individual reported their emotions in 3 to 5 situations (therefore,
  description of the situation was categorized). So I have dependent
  data.

Is it possible to analyze the association between situation categories and emotion categories with correspondence analysis? Is it a problem that my data has 80 situations reported by 20 individuals?

The table of data looks like this:

```
                    Anger — Helples
Situation conflict. 21      12
Situation ….        11     15
Etc.
```

Comment: Why do mean by "analyzing the association between situation categories and emotion categories"? In a usual setting, what would you use correspondence analysis for?